# simple string deserialize issue

Tags: asp.net, json, json-deserialization

I am getting an error something like tis when convertning string to object.
**Sayfalar' type doent support for the array series.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var jsonObjectKnt = serializer.Deserialize<Sayfalar>(data);
// **I got error here 
my data like that 
data:"[{\"Id\":1,\"MenuAd\": \"ANASAYFAccz\",\"Baslik\": \"BASLIK ANA cccz\".....
```

Comment: JSON.Net ..... might be a good option for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the square brackets, it works fine.